# Can a SharePoint Calculated field check for existence of other columns?

Tags: sharepoint, sql-order-by, calculated-field, spsitedataquery

I want to use `OrderBy` in `SPSiteDataQuery` to sort items by data, however, the field containing the date differs between the content types.

Can this be solved by sorting with a calculated field? I am currently trying to create a calculated field that checks for existence of a field (using [`ISERROR`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/is-functions-HA001161040.aspx)), if it is found it returns the value, otherwise returns a default value. Or perhaps I can create a Calculated field in parent content type, then override it's formula and field references in a child content type - would such polymorphism work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out - **NO**, it can't.